# How do I listen for custom events in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to do something like

```dart
// WARNING: this code does not work, it's illustrative
query("#myBtn").onClick.listen((e) {
  window.fire["foo"];
});

window.on["foo"].listen((e) => print("foo was here"));

window.on["foo"].listen((e) => print("and here"));
```

Is it possible? How? I've been searching on Google for a few hours now, but I'm kind of new to programming in general, so I don't really know any keywords for this sort of thing.

Thanks! :)

-- EDIT: Solved --

Here's how to pass arguments along (The editor will complain, but it works)

```dart
List<String> myData = ["one","two"];

query("#myBtn").onClick.listen((e) {
  window.on["foo"].dispatch(new CustomEvent("foo", canBubble: false, cancelable: false, detail: myData));
});

window.on["foo"].add((e) => print( e.detail[1] ));
```

:-)

Comment: To avoid editor "warnings", last sentence could be written as follow: `window.on["foo"].add((CustomEvent e) => print((e.detail as List<String>)[1]));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
window.on['foo'].listen((e) => print("foo was here"));
```

See the docs:

- http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Events.html

Comment: I did read those, but at my (low) level, it's nearly impossible to understand.
What you wrote works perfectly, and I'll give you the points. But I'd be happy if you could also help me with passing arguments in it. :)

Comment: This snippet does not work any more @SethLadd @JustinFagnani . There is no `dispatch` on the `_EventStream`. I guess we need to use `Element.dispatchEvent` instead?

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov that's how I do it. I'll clean up the answer to be more specific to the original question.

Answer (score 15):

You said you wanted to pass around data. Let's assume we have this class:

```dart
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

then this listener:

```dart
window.on['foo'].listen((e) {
  Person p = e.detail;

  print(p.name); // Jack
});
```

All we need to pass data around is to write something like:

```dart
var p = new Person()
  ..name = 'Jack'
  ..age = 25;

var e = new CustomEvent('foo', detail: p);

window.on['foo'].dispatch(e);
```

This is the way to do it. See the documentation:

- http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Events.html
- http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CustomEvent.html

Comment: Exactly. This is a better way of writing what I tried to write myself after the edit :)