# How to dispatch events in Dart?

Tags: dart

I read this question: [How do I listen for custom events in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897091/how-do-i-listen-for-custom-events-in-dart)

It tells you to dispatch events like:

```
window.on['foo'].dispatch(new CustomEvent('foo'));
```

However, with the latest version of Dart SDK, the `on` is deprecated. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent code in the latest SDK would be like:

```dart
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foo'));
```

It does not need to be any harder than that ;)