# dart how to create, listen, and emits custom event?

Tags: dart

I have class like this :

```
class BaseModel {
  Map objects;

  // define constructor here

  fetch() {
    // fetch json from server and then load it to objects
    // emits an event here
  }

}
```

Like `backbonejs` i want to emits a `change` event when i call `fetch` and create a listener for `change` event on my view.

But from reading the documentation, i don't know where to start since there are so many that points to event, like `Event` `Events` `EventSource` and so on.

Can you guys give me a hint?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I am assuming you want to emit events that do not require the presence of `dart:html` library.

You can use the Streams API to expose a stream of events for others to listen for and handle. Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class BaseModel {
  Map objects;
  StreamController fetchDoneController = new StreamController.broadcast();

  // define constructor here

  fetch() {
    // fetch json from server and then load it to objects
    // emits an event here
    fetchDoneController.add("all done"); // send an arbitrary event
  }

  Stream get fetchDone => fetchDoneController.stream;

}
```

Then, over in your app:

```dart
main() {
  var model = new BaseModel();
  model.fetchDone.listen((_) => doCoolStuff(model));
}
```

Using the native Streams API is nice because it means you don't need the browser in order to test your application.

If you are required to emit a custom HTML event, you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902121/123471

Comment: 1) fetchDoneController  seems 'final' to me but more important 2) say i want to subscribe to *any* fetch event with the classical scheme where the sender is identified by e.sender or like. I could i do that in Dart ? i guess with a static StreamController, but i do i access the static stream ? I'd be glad you if you provided an example for such case (or i may ask a question on SO...).

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for it:
https://pub.dev/packages/event

This will be better than using Streams as 'event' is more readable