# Event coding in Dart/Flutter: Why is it inside the dart:html package, and should I use Steams API instead for non web related events?

Tags: flutter, dart, events, stream

I would like to program event listening code in Dart/Flutter, then I found the answer at [dart how to create, listen, and emits custom event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717681/dart-how-to-create-listen-and-emits-custom-event) and [How do I listen for custom events in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897091/how-do-i-listen-for-custom-events-in-dart/13902121#13902121)

Which made me wonder:
1: Why are the event related classes inside the `dart:html` package? Wouldn't that differ from other programming languages, and what's the reason behind this language design?

2: Should I adapt and use Streams API in Dart for event codings that are not necessarily related to web?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a package for it:
https://pub.dev/packages/event

After I learnt more about Flutter, it seems it is a better choice to use Provider or its alternative like Riverpod to achieve the same purpose https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options